# How to modify dumpdata generated django json fixture prior to loading into database

Tags: django, django-fixtures

I am a relative django newbie. I have a json fixture for the django.contrib.auth.user objects from an existing database that I want to load into my test app. The specific field I want to modify are all the Datetime Fields that do not have UTC offsets built into them. I want to add these UTC offsets using a python script.

I am using the django deserializer but am having no luck and get an error during the deserialization.

```
  File "add_utc_offset_to_fixture.py", line 24, in <module>
    for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", json_fixture):
  File "/Users/hari/.virtualenvs/bsc2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/serializers/json.py", line 47, in Deserializer
    raise DeserializationError(e)
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: No module named Image
```

How do I get around this deserialization error, or alternatively how do I modify this fixtures before loading into the database.

I looked into my fixtures and also into the json.py deserializer and do not understand why it needs a module called Image.

My code

```
# This program reads in a json fixture with naive Datetime field and converts it into a UTC aware Datetime field
# For Documentation on this see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#time-zones-migration-guide
import sys,os

# Sets the django settings module
dir_two_steps_up_from_me = os.path.join(os.path.split(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))[-2])
print "Adding %s to sys.path" % dir_two_steps_up_from_me
sys.path.append(dir_two_steps_up_from_me)

from bsc2 import settings
from django.core.management import setup_environ
# Deprecated but still using
setup_environ(settings)

from django.core import serializers

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
json_fixture = None
try:
    json_fixture = open(sys.argv[1],"rb")
except IndexError,IOError:
    print "Please give json fixture"
    exit()

for obj in serializers.deserialize("json", json_fixture):
    # Getting deserialization error when this executes
    print obj.first_name
    # TODO Code to change naive time in last_login to UTC time
```

Comment: Double check that you have PIL installed.

Comment: I installed PIL and then this error went away. But I wanted to find out why it requires the Image module. The deserialization is just loading User objects into the database. The Image module is only required at runtime